# How does python know the word is a str?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to understand how exactly does python know that the word variable is actually a word here:

```
for word in file.read().lower().split():
```

file here is a .txt file and that was the only  thing defined prior to this function. Plus, imported collections module

I am a beginner, would appreciate it so much if someone can explain me this probably super basic fundamental thing here.

Comment: Because every "value" carries its "type" with it, rather than every "variable"

Comment: Whenever you call a function (like `.read()` or `.lower()` etc or even something like `print()`) it has a return value. For `print()` that's `None` and you typically ignore that, but for a function like `.split()`, the return type is a list of strings - so if you use a for loop to iterate over that list, the loop variable `word` will be assigned the elements from that list, i.e. a string `str` - @donkopotamus is correct, the type is associated with the value (here the value returned by the function) and the variable is just assigned that value (and has that type as a result)

Comment: "how exactly does python know that the word variable is actually a word here:" I don't understand why you think it does "know" any such thing. I also am not clear on which is the question - about whether it's a *string* (like in the title), or whether it's a "word" (like in the question itself). But "words" aren't a separate type in Python, they're just strings that happen to represent a word. Just like "odd integers" aren't a special type; they're just integers that happen not to divide evenly by 2.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems like you have a general lack of understanding about how some aspect of the language works, and are having difficulty explaining the question properly because you don't have that grounding. You should probably try to follow a tutorial instead of asking here. It's hard to answer the question properly because, in the terms in which you want to use to think about the situation, there isn't a meaningful question.

Comment: You did not define what a `word` is; i/e you are probably conflating your own understanding of what a `word` "should be", and the variable name you are using.

Comment: python doesn't understand concept of "WORD".   The .split() separates a list of characters by space (' ').   Regardless of its content.   So in your example, .split() returns a python list of list.    

"abc def ghi 123 *() xyz" .split()

will return list of list
["abc", 
"def", 
"ghi",
"123",
"*()",
"xyz"]

the string "abc" is really a list of characters (STRING)

Comment: `word` is not necessarily a `str`; it could be a `bytes` if `file` was opened as binary, but that seems unlikely for a TXT file.

Comment: What do you mean by "know"? Please [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Python does not, in fact, know that `word` is a word.  That's just a variable name chosen by the programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To break it down, in your code (assuming you have something like the `open` here):

```
with open('my.txt') as file:
    for word in file.read().lower().split():
        ...
```

- `file` is a file, specifically a text file, since no `'b'` was passed to indicate it's a binary file instead
- calling `file.read()` returns the contents of the file, and because it knows it is a text file, that function returns a string value
- calling `file.read().lower()` is therefore calling `.lower()` on that string value and *it* also returns a string value (the entire string, in lowercase)
- finally, `file.read().lower().split()` operates on *that* string value, splitting it in to a `list`, specifically a list of `str`
- `for word in <some iterable>` therefore loops over a `list` of `str` and that's why the value of `word` will be a `str` in the `for`-loop body - each lowercase word from the text file, one at a time for each iteration.

In case the confusion arises from the naming: the fact that the variable is called `word` has no bearing on the type of the value assigned to it. This code would do the exact same, and `square` would be a string:

```
with open('my.txt') as blue:
    for square in blue.read().lower().split():
        ...
```

The variable names are decided on by the programmer and have to follow some rules, but don't 'mean' anything. The function names were decide by whoever wrote the module they are in, so `.read()`, `.lower()` etc. have been named by the designers of Python itself.

And functions can return different types of values, depending on all kinds of factors. For example, here's a function that adds one to a value, but leaves the type of the value unchanged:

```
def add_one(x):
    if isinstance(x, (float, int)):
        # this works for either a float or an int, Python's + leaves that alone
        return x + 1
    elif isinstance(x, str):
        try:
            # perhaps it's an integer literal
            return str(int(x) + 1)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                # or perhaps a float literal
                return str(float(x) + 1)
            except ValueError:
                raise ValueError(f'x is a string, but not a float or int: {e}')
    else:
        raise ValueError('unsupported type for add_one: {type(x)}')


x = 1
x = add_one(x)  # x still an int
y = 1.0
y = add_one(y)  # y still a float
a = '1'
a = add_one(a)  # a still a string (of an int)
b = '1.0'
b = add_one(b)  # a still a string (of a float)

# make python print what the values would look like in a Python list
print(repr([x, y, a, b]))

# but the next line fails with an exception
c = 'one'
c = add_one(c)
```

Ends up printing:

```
[2, 2.0, '2', '2.0']
```

But then fails with

```
ValueError: x is a string, but not a float or int: could not convert string to float: 'one'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes so much sense now.

Comment: You're welcome - feel free to accept the answer by ticking the checkmark, so the question no longer appears as unanswered. That helps others find the answer and prevents people answering questions from spending time on a question that's already answered.

Comment: Great, just did. Thanks!!